# How to use a nested element as a table cell

Tags: css

Imagine the following HTML:

```
<div class='leaderboard'>
    <div class='entry'>
        <div class='contestant'>
            <div class='name'>Robert</div>
            <div class='country'>Ireland</div>
        </div>
        <div class='score'>32</div>
    </div>
    <div class='entry'>
        <div class='contestant'>
            <div class='name'>Dan</div>
            <div class='country'>USA</div>
        </div>
        <div class='score'>81</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, we all know that we can use CSS to make this a two-column table:

```
.leaderboard {
    display: table;
}
.entry {
    display: table-row;
}
.contestant, .score {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

This will render the contestant’s name and country within one cell, and the score in another.

What I want is to be able to have three columns, with the name, country, and score, but without changing the HTML. Is this possible?

In other words, ideally, I want to be able to tell the renderer to ignore the `<div class='contestants'>` entirely and pretend that `name` and `country` are children of the table row.

Comment: The nesting of name and country under contestant does not logically allow this.

Comment: @johannes, why CSS3 instead of CSS? what CSS3 features are involved here?

Comment: @Johannes it was defined at the level2 (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) not 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to tell the renderer to ignore the `<div class='contestants'>` entirely and pretend that name and country are children of the table row.

This is what `display:contents;` will do (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents)

> causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element itself.

```css
.leaderboard {
  display: table;
}

.entry {
  display: table-row;
}


.score,
.name,
.country{
  display: table-cell;
  padding:10px;
}

.contestant {
 display:contents;
}
```

```html
<div class='leaderboard'>
  <div class='entry'>
    <div class='contestant'>
      <div class='name'>Robert</div>
      <div class='country'>Ireland</div>
    </div>
    <div class='score'>32</div>
  </div>
  <div class='entry'>
    <div class='contestant'>
      <div class='name'>Dan</div>
      <div class='country'>USA</div>
    </div>
    <div class='score'>81</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, your link shows that there's no IE and Edge support for that :-/ Can anybody afford not to support IE?

Comment: @Johannes yes it's a new feature but it does exactly what the OP said, so it worth being an answer since it has good support on modern browsers

Comment: hmm - I also don't like Edge but I guess it's still considered a "modern" browser...